# Get & Edit NSMutableArray from different class file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to access and change a array from a different class file. When using a NSLog, I get a result of (null). Below is my code:

**RootViewController.h**

```
NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
```

**RootViewController.m**

```
@synthesize listOfItems;
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listOfItems addObject:@"One"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"Two"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"Three"];
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
RootViewController *test = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Results: %@", test.listOfItems);
```

I get the following results in my console: `Results: (null)`

Thanks in advance,
Coulton

*P.S. Obviously I have left out a bunch of code. I just tried to make it easier to read. If you need to see anything else, I would be more than happy to post more. Just ask*

**EDIT #1:**

I am getting hundreds of NSLog Messages that look something like this:

```
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e39020 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

And here's my init code:

```
- (id) init {

//NSLog(@"%@", theUserID);
// Set up database connection
NSString *myDB = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];
database = [[Sqlite alloc] init];
[database open:myDB];

//Initialize the array.
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Add to array to display in the tableView
NSArray *listOfItemsTwo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM albums"];  
for (NSDictionary *rowone in listOfItemsTwo) {
    NSString *getName = [rowone valueForKey:@"name"];
    if (getName != NULL) {
        [listOfItems addObject:getName];
        [getName release];
    }
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you reversed RootViewController.m and RootViewController.h snippets right?

Are you sure that the

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

gets called? Maybe you can put a breakpoint there.

EDIT: Order of RootViewController.m and RootViewController.h has been fixed in the question. It's not clear from the question where the above line is in the code. That's a important piece of information.

EDIT2: Example of init method.

```
@implementation RootViewController
- (id) init
{
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"One"];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. And it gets called in the `viewDidLoad`. It does get populated (it shows in my tableView before I do this action). Should I try putting it in my `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: You should put it in the init function. That's what you are calling in your line: RootViewController *test = [[RootViewController alloc] init]; Unless it is in your init function it makes sense that you won't see it in your next line.

Comment: This might be a stupid question - but what is the INIT function?

Comment: init is defined just like any other function. Nothing special. Your line RootViewController *test = [[RootViewController alloc] init]; is calling the 'alloc' function of the RootviewController class which returns an object and then calls the init function of that object.

Comment: Thanks so much! Stackoverflow to the rescue again! Now, when implementing it with the real-life application I get a error that says I have no pool set. My code is the post above.

Comment: You need to define an autorelease pool. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html. You can probably look at just about any sample APP, they will all have an autorelease pool define somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply. I already used "database" somewhere else in the file. I used a different name and it worked perfectly! Thanks.